# I would like to know the difference between function and method in C#

Tags: c#, function, methods

Example code for my question

```
MessageBox.Show();// is a method and
and private void Example()
{

} //is a function?
is there any real difference or not, please explain
```

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: A method is a function attached to an object. The only non-method functions in C# I can think of are lambdas.

Comment: A function typically returns a value, whereas a method is a broader term which includes functions but also includes subroutines that don't return a value.

Comment: I have always understood them the way @rory.ap stated.  Functions return values.  Methods typically don't, but the term 'method' can be loosely tossed around (in C# these are also referred to as `Action`s).

Comment: There really is no difference. And [MessageBox.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_MessageBox_Show_System_String_) does indeed return a value of type `DialogResult `

Answer (score 3):

Let's first get the general definition of what `function` means in a Computer Science sense:

> Functions are "self contained" modules of code that accomplish a
> specific task. Functions usually "take in" data, process it, and
> "return" a result. Once a function is written, it can be used over and
> over and over again. Functions can be "called" from the inside of
> other functions.

or another definition:

> In programming, a named section of a program that performs a specific
> task is called a function. In this sense, a function is a type of
> procedure or routine. Some programming languages make a distinction
> between a function, which returns a value, and a procedure, which
> performs some operation but does not return a value.

By these definitions, just about every named code block that can perform a repeatable task when called is a function, though some languages would have that code return a value.

However, in C# according to the ECMA specifications, the word *function* is very rarely used (comparatively), and can mean something very specifically (depending on the context) or define a large subset of language features.

Notable mentions from the ECMA C# Specifications

1. Anonymous functions

> An anonymous-method-expression or lambda-expression is classified as
> an anonymous function

2. Function members

> Function members are members that contain executable statements.
> Function members are always members of types and cannot be members of
> namespaces. C# defines the following categories of function members:
>
> - Methods
> - Properties
> - Events
> - Indexers
> - User-defined operators
> - Instance constructors
> - Static constructors
> - Finalizers

3. Async Functions

> A method (§15.6) or anonymous function (§12.16) with the async
> modifier is called an async function. In general, the term async is
> used to describe any kind of function that has the async modifier. It
> is a compile-time error for the formal parameter list of an async
> function to specify any ref or out parameters.

4. Local functions

> Starting with C# 7.0, C# supports local functions. Local functions are
> private methods of a type that are nested in another member. They can
> only be called from their containing member.

In short, trying to determine what a function is and isn't in C# is problematic at best (you should worry about other things). Most of the time the terminology of *method* and *function* can be used interchangeably, however it also can be used to describe a very specific named language feature (as seen above).

People could argue about the historical definition forever or quote specs to prove the point either way. However, for what you should be concerned with (at this level) is that most things you would think of as methods or functions are actually both (with few exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

A function in C# (or more precise ["local function"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)) is a function defined inside another method.

Both examples in the post show "methods" returning a value. There is no naming difference whether method returns a value or void, or whether value returned by a call to the method is used or not.

The other types of syntactic constructs in C# that you can call "function" (in addition to local functions and methods):

- constructors
- property and event accessors (also you probably should avoid calling them functions, at very least not automatically generated once)
- anonymous methods/functions striclty called [anonymous function expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#anonymous-function-expressions)
- lambda expressions
- finalizers (also you probably should stick with another wrong name than calling it function - "destructor" if you really don't like proper "finalizer").

Answer (score -2):

Your Example() is a method definition, whereas MessageBox.Show() is a method that is being called.   MessageBox.Show() also has a definition but it isn't in your code, it is in the .Net code.